# Prove a property of the weight decomposition of representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I try to prove the following property of complete decomposition of the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$:

> Show if $V$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, then 
>   $$V\cong \bigoplus n_k V_k$$
>   and $n_k=\dim V[k]-\dim V[k+2]$.

The last part (about $n_k$ and the dimension of the eigenspace) seems to be a very amazing result for me.

Since $V_k$ does not contain $V[k+2]$. And we can take any numbers of copies of $V_k$. So I am really confused here since I think these two numbers at each side are totally irrelevant. So I must miss something very crucial. Please point it out. Thanks!

Comment: It's much easier if you know beforehand that every rep splits as direct sum of the $V_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $V_k$ are the standard irrep of weight $k$. Then, consider multiplication by $x : V[k] \to V[k+2]$. Clearly, $x$ is surjective and moreover, $x(v) = 0$ iff $v$ is a heighest weight vector of weight $k$. So $\dim \ker(x) = \dim V[k] - \dim V[k+2]$ is indeed $n_k$.

Here is an intuitive explanation : there are two kind of eigenvector of weight $k$, the one which spans an irrep $V_k$ and the one which comes from irrep of bigger weight. For example, if $w \in V_{k+2}$, then $y(w) \in V_k$ is a vector of "second kind". Now, by definition, the "second kind" vectors are *exactly* the vectors which are not killed when multiplied by $x$. So $\dim \ker x$ is the number you were looking for, and it is $\dim V[k] - \dim V[k+2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It turns out to be very easy...

Comment: @LeoGardon : you are welcome ! (in fact I added an explanation just in case). Also, I think few month ago I did also wrote something about blowing up an $A_3$ singularity, was it useful ?

Comment: Thank you again for the great comments! As for the $A_3$ singularity answer, sorry for the long-term silence since now I am restudying the Hartshorne Chapter 1 systematically so that I can have enough background and I planned to digest your answer after I finish the Chap 1. Hope I can understand your answer soon and accept it :)

Comment: No problems I know that it can take some time :) 
I would advice to study Fulton's book on curve and Reid's lecture notes on arxiv about surfaces, it was a good way for me. I found Hartshorne a bit too abstract and I think it's easier to appreciate it once you already know intuitively what is going on. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I will follow your advice!